# In helmcharts, how to combine a list with multiple fields per element into a string?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have a list that has multiple fields per element, and I would need to concatenate it into a comma separated string that has fields foo and bar separated with a semicolon.

```
myList:
  - foo: "asdf"
    bar: "hnng"
  - foo: "meh"
    bar: "dunno"
```

For example, the above would need to be concatenated into "asdf;hnng,meh;dunno".

You could iterate through the list with range, but how would you then pass on that list to join? For example, the following should produce a list of strings, but how would I then pass it into join function?

```
{{- range .Values.myList }}
  - {{.foo}};{{.bar}}
{{- end}

=>

- asdf;hnng
- meh;dunno
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

values.yaml

```yaml
myList:
  - foo: "asdf"
    bar: "hnng"
  - foo: "meh"
    bar: "dunno"
```

template

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  data: |-
    {{- $str := "" }}
    {{- range $i, $e := .Values.myList }}
    {{- if $i }}
    {{- $str = print $str "," }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- $str = print $str $e.foo ";" $e.bar }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- $str | nindent 4 }}
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  data: |-
    asdf;hnng,meh;dunno
```

Answer (score 0):

The Go `text/template` language doesn't have a generic `map` function or anything else that would make it possible to transform a list into another list.  You need to rewrite this to emit the whole string in one block, it's probably not going to be possible to construct an input to `join`.

When you iterate through the outer list, you can get the current index and then use that to decide whether to set a separator:

```
{{- $index, $item := range .Values.myList -}}
{{- if ne $index 0 -}},{{- end -}}
{{- $item.foo -}};{{- $item.bar -}}
{{- end -}}
```

It's possible to make this a lot more complicated - split out the individual item into its own template, change the loop to a recursive template call - but fundamentally you need to emit the list-item separators yourself.